# Numpy array no longer flattens inputs once upgrading to 1.16

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Upgrading a codebase from numpy 1.15.2 to 1.16.6 and observing a deviation in the behavior of the numpy.array. python version 3.6.7.

Previous behavior (numpy 1.15.2):

```
sequence=(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, array([5.]))
old_array = numpy.array(sequence)
print(old_array)
array([1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 5.0])
```

New behavior (numpy 1.16.6):

```
sequence=(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, array([5.]))
new_array = numpy.array(sequence)
print(new_array)
array([1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, array([5.])], dtype=object)
```

In these examples array([5]) corresponds to a numpy.ndarray of a singular element. Sequence is a tuple of value passed to numpy.array function. With version 1.15.2 numpy.array essentially flattened the single element array while 1.16.6 concatenated it as an additional element.

Nothing in the release notes for numpy 1.16.* seems to imply a change in behavior for the array creation function. If the goal is to simply flatten the array numpy.hstack could work, however I am looking for an explanation for the change in behavior as it could have other ramifications in the codebase I am upgrading.

Comment: What was the `dtype` in the earlier version.  If that was an accurate copy-n-paste, I suspect there was just a change in display, not an actual flattening.  Note that the `5` is integer, not float like the other elements.

Comment: @hpaulj I apologize this was a transcription error. The value in the inner array is a float, such that sequence = (1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, array([5.]). What seems to have changed is that numpy.array changed from treating the sequence as floats to treating them as objects.

Comment: I've been getting this warning whenver I do this for a while, presumably since before the behavior changed: `<stdin>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that may be related. The behavior I am interested in understanding is that at some point numpy.array changed from inferring the dtype in my example as numpy.float64 to inferring it as object. If I explicitly pass dtype=numpy.float64 to the numpy.array call the behavior matches the behavior of numpy 1.15. I am mainly just interested in why this change occurred.

Answer (score 0):

In my comments I focused on a change in display, to include an explicit `array` word.  But I couldn't find that documented in the release notes.  And even without that your example should display as `[1.5,1.5,[5.]]`.

But in a current version (1.19):

```
In [99]: np.array([1.5,1.5,np.array(5)])
Out[99]: array([1.5, 1.5, 5. ])
```

Here the 0d `np.array(5)` is "flattened", that is treated the same as floats.

While the 1d array produces the ragged warning (as of 1.19) and object dtype:

```
In [100]: np.array([1.5,1.5,np.array([5])])
<ipython-input-100-41ccaf61f1ba>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  np.array([1.5,1.5,np.array([5])])
Out[100]: array([1.5, 1.5, array([5])], dtype=object)
```

If instead I explicitly set the dtype to float:

```
In [101]: np.array([1.5,1.5,np.array([5])],float)
Out[101]: array([1.5, 1.5, 5. ])
```

So it is possible that in 1.15, the (1,) array was being treated the same as the () shape one.

If I had an earlier version, I'd check the `dtype`, and also test expressions like `np.array([1.5, 1.5, np.array([1,2])])`.

`np.array` is a complex function.  The default behavior is to create a multidimensional numeric (or string) dtype array.  Failing that it falls back on making an object dtype array (and now with a warning).  But for some combinations of shapes it raises an error.

```
In [103]: np.array([np.ones((2,1)), np.ones((2,3))],object)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-103-b2aa52476628>", line 1, in <module>
    np.array([np.ones((2,1)), np.ones((2,3))],object)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,1) into shape (2)
```

The VisibleDeprecationWarning tells us that `numpy` developers are moving toward cleaning up this `np.array` behavior, removing the fall back behaviors that often trap novice users.

Comment: Thank you for the response @hpaulj! It appears between numpy 1.15 -> 1.16 the change was to infer dtype=object if any of the elements in the sequence are list/tuples/arrays. This means in numpy 1.15 np.array([1.5, 1.5, np.array([1.5, 1.5]) will error unless type=object is passed. While in 1.16 np.array([1.5, 1.5, np.array([1.5, 1.5]) works fine, inferring dtype=object. I suspect this dtype deduction impacted the previous logic which treated the (1,) array as a float instead of an object. And then in 1.19 the warning was added. Still wish I could find documentation of this change of handling.